# How do I find which nested namespace to import in C# for the classes I need in my code?

Tags: c#, namespaces

This is one of the things I find infuriating about C#. I have thsi massive library im trying to use right now and for some reason the people who create the code examples are not smart enough to include the namespaces you need to import in the examples. This is usualyl the case. I find myself searching through the namespace, hundreds sometimes nested trying to figure out which ones i need to import. In java netbeans, it even tells me which packages to import because it searches for me. But in C# i always waste countless time searching through the namespace manually.

Is there any way I can get around this. Like right now im trying to find which namespace contains TwitterCredentials for Tweetinvi library.

Seriously, why do people not include the namespace in code examples. It's just stupid not to!
And why does visual studio not make suggestions like java. It's just common sense really....

Comment: just get resharper , I'm pretty sure there is a free trial and they all get included automatically for you.  That is what most developers use.

Comment: thanks dude just downloading it!

Comment: you never tried to Google TwitterCredentials namespace ??  I found Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Service.Security  in 1 sec

Comment: It is right on top of the MSDN page.  "Namespace" is what you ask for, "Assembly" is what you need to reference.

Comment: yeh i did google it and for some reason didnt see that :/?

Comment: thats not right anyway. thats not the one!

Comment: im using tweetinvi library

Answer (score 6):

You can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> on each word that has error or point to small blue bar under the word and click on dropdown, and use offered namespace.

[image]

Comment: like i should be able to set up credentials by calling this static function and it says the function doesnt exist TwitterCredentials.SetCredentials("Access_Token", "Access_Token_Secret", "Consumer_Key", "Consumer_Secret");

Comment: yet its documented on the webpage i keep finding this with every single library i use. It's a little silly.

Comment: That feature doesn't know anything about static methods of your classes, it helps you to resolve namespace problems:)

Comment: In order to title of your question **how do I find which nested namespace to import in C# for the classes i need in my code?** I think it may help to future users to resolve namespaces more simple.

Comment: yes but when i resolved the namespace the namespace doesnt contain that functn at all. It's ridiculous. This keeps happening with different libraries i use, functions missing. I wonder if there is something wrong with visual studio. It gest on my nerves.

Comment: I think when you work with visual studio for long time, you will learn good features that makes application development such fast that you have not ever seen;)

Comment: yes but right now visual studio doesnt seem to be working right. The function which should be inside a class is completley missing from the library.

Comment: To be honest I have not ever seen a mistake using this command and I guess probably you are missing something and probably you have a tiny mistake:)

Answer (score 0):

I am the developer of Tweetinvi :)

ALL the classes you need in Tweetinvi are located in the Tweetinvi.Core.* namespace.

[TwitterCredentials.cs](https://github.com/linvi/tweetinvi/blob/Tweetinvi-0.9.10.0/Tweetinvi.Core/Credentials/TwitterCredentials.cs)

To answer your question regarding Namespaces and why I do not include them in the examples. The reason is that as mentioned by Reza Aghaei Visual Studio and Resharper allow developers to include namespaces.

Furthermore as you mentioned the library is big and therefore multiple namespaces might be required and I am not going to add all of them in each example. Otherwise the documentation would just be huge.

I hope you will like the library and please feel free to ask any question here on stackoverflow or on [github](https://github.com/linvi/tweetinvi).

Happy coding.

PS: By the way you can also use Github to search for filename with a 't' keystroke on the Source Code page.